# How to support GCM service for minimum version 8 in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-build

How to support Android minimum SDK version 8 for Google play GCM service [com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0]. In my application I have set minimum SDK version 8 and targeting version 23 and need Google GCM service to my app, so that I have added corresponding dependencies to the app.

This is gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mg"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile project(':sliderlibrary')
}
```

Got the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0] /home/node/mg_android_studio/MeterGenius/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-gcm/8.4.0/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.gcm" to force usage
```

How to get support for minimum version 8?. Please help me.

Comment: Personally I would advice to just increase the minimum version. as you can see on http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html only 0.1% off all people run version 8

Answer (score 1):

Follow the suggestion in the error message and add the following to your Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.gcm"/>
```

Be prepared however that GCM might not work as expected on SDK 8.